# How could I make cells of table bigger?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I got a table where the cells width are aligned with the table header, which gives something like this:

```
[STUDENT] -> th
[name of
student ] -> td
```

I would like to make the width of the th as big as the biggest  in order to give something like this:

```
[STUDENT         ] -> th
[name of student ] -> td
```

I hope I am being clear because I don't really know how I could explain this differently.

Comment: Could you post your HTML to show what you've tried and so that people can reproduce the problem

Comment: Try setting table width.

Comment: The issue is that the html is generated with javascript :/

Comment: You can still make a [mcve] using the generated HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED
Just had padding to the td like:

```
<th style="padding-right:10px">EXAMPLE</th>
```

Comment: Remember to say it was solved in the question so people can see it :)

Answer (score 0):

@Bruno Moutinho's answer is wrong. This isn't what you asked to do.

You aren't looking for having always space on the right of your table, the true answer should be:

```
th {
    min-width: 500px;
}
```

500 is an example number, but you can just use a default number, or via javascript, calculate the minimum necessary width and then set it to the th.